# q/Kdb+ Vector Conditional to update and iterate over rows in a column of a table

Tags: kdb

I am trying to update a column in my table using the vector conditional function in kdb+ such that after each conditional is tested, the value outputted is based on the output value previous in the row above but same column. Suppose I have a table as such:

```
t:([] number:-100 100 600 -200 -400f);
t: update cumsum: sums[number] from t;
t: update signumcumsum: signum cumsum from t;
t: update role:1b from t;
```

| number | cumsum | signumcumsum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -100 | -100 | -1 |
| 100 | 0 | 0 |
| 600 | 600 | +1 |
| -200 | 400 | +1 |
| -400 | 0 | 0 |

And now I would like to use a vector conditional to update each role such that each value is based on the previous value in the row above. My command is

```
t: update role: ?[(signumcumsum)=(prev signumcumsum);1^prev role;not 1^prev role] from t;
```

And I intend the table to look like this

| number | cumsum | signumcumsum | role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -100 | -100 | -1 | 1b |
| 100 | 0 | 0 | 0b |
| 600 | 600 | +1 | 1b |
| -200 | 400 | +1 | 1b |
| -400 | 0 | 0 | 0b |

However the table outputted in the console is like this:

| number | cumsum | signumcumsum | role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -100 | -100 | -1 | 1b |
| 100 | 0 | 0 | 1b |
| 600 | 600 | +1 | 1b |
| -200 | 400 | +1 | 1b |
| -400 | 0 | 0 | 1b |

Is there something wrong with my logic or how I am writing the code? Would much appreciate any corrections or advice.

Comment: Don't post the same question again. Instead, update the original in accordance with the feedback you received.

Comment: @tripleee this is the first question i hv posted. could u clarify what u mean?

Comment: Then why does it say "This post is hidden. You deleted this post just now."?

Comment: You are missing a line before updating `role` as this requires the `role` column to exist first.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up I see what u mean, except the vector conditional update still generates the same result.

Comment: I've run all your lines and I'm not getting what you're seeing .... are you sure it's not doing what you intend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potentially there are 2 issues with your logic.

1. Using `prev` on a Boolean list gives `0b` for the first element, not a null value. You are trying to fill a null value, but there are none.
2. The previous `role` value is not carrying forward like you expect.

I can get the expected output by fixing point 2. Here I used scan `\` to continually modify the `role` value, which starts as `1b`. This carries the previous `role` value forward.

```
q)update role:{[role;signumcumsum;prevSCS]$[signumcumsum=prevSCS;role;not role]}\[1b;signumcumsum;prev[first signumcumsum;signumcumsum]] from t
number cumsum signumcumsum role
-------------------------------
-100   -100   -1           1
100    0      0            0
600    600    1            1
-200   400    1            1
-400   0      0            0
```

Note the use of `prev[first signumcumsum;signumcumsum]` here which ensures the initial `role` value is `1b`.